# Visual Studio doesn't autocomplete

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Using c#

My Visual Studio suddenly stopped autocompleting me while I write.
for clarification, it does show me the normal completion options but it doesn't highlight the best one, meaning I can't just click enter and it will complete for the best match.

example:
when I write "flo", it suggests "float" but I can't just click enter and it will auto-complete.

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to 1) disable all your extensions 2) [reset your configuration](https://www.technipages.com/visual-studio-reset-all-settings) (backup first, if you have custom settings) 3) Use [repair option](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?  Different things.

Comment: @Mark visual studio

Answer (score 0):

> example: when I write "flo", it suggests "float" but I can't just click enter and it will auto-complete.

It sounds like you want the other Intellisense mode, the option is called "toggle IntelliSense suggestion/completion mode" and in the C# configuration the shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+Space:

[image]